# wx_python is not loading while creating Installer using PyInstaller

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyinstaller

I am trying to create a Python 64 bit installer using [PyInstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/).

While creating an `.exe` I am getting an error message like:

```
wx_python is not loading
```

In short, the module named `wx.lib.pubsub` in `wx_python` is not loading.
But its working when I run it in the `Python IDE` (Python 2.7).

What could be the problem? How can it be solved?